Beamer with two different fonts families
I'm trying to use two different fonts in Beamer, stix2 and regular Computer Modern. In fact, I just want to use regular Computer Modern in some words (which can be in mathmode) via predefined command. My code is the following:
\documentclass[portuguese,notheorems]{beamer}

%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{stix2}

\providecommand\myset{\textbf}

\begin{document}
I'm using \texttt{stix2} package and I want that my command \texttt{myset} produces text in Computer Modern \texttt{[T1]\{fontenc\}}. 
\end{document}

Any help is very welcome.

Do you mean serif or sans serif computer modern if you talk about "regular Computer Modern"?

For regular Computer Modern, I mean the usual font used in LaTeX, for instance, when we use\documentclass{article} as the following example ```\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
I want this font.
\end{document}```

Wouldn't the serif version of stix be a better match: \textrm{some text in serif}?

If I cannot use Computer Modern simultaneously with stix2 in Beamer, then I don't have another choice than  \textrm...

You can use computer modern roman and stix simultaneously, but they might not be the nicest looking combination.

You can use \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont to switch back to roman computer modern font (don't worry about the T1 encoding, you already get it from loading stix2). However, using the serif version of stix2 may look better:
\documentclass[portuguese,notheorems]{beamer}

\usepackage{stix2}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\myset[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont #1%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Test

\textrm{Test}

\myset{Test}

Test
\end{frame}
\end{document}



It's great! With thanks.

@Carlos You're welcome!
